# TypeScript not seeing defined types using a type that references multiple types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have a type defined that looks like this:

```
export type MediaProps = ImageMediaProps | OembedProps;
```

Then have the types it's referencing defined as the following above that code:

```
type SharedMediaProps = {
  /** Media type */
  type: "image" | "oembed";
  /** Media source URL */
  src: string;
};

type ImageMediaProps = SharedMediaProps & {
  /** Image alternate text */
  alt: string;
  /** Image width */
  width: number;
  /** Image height */
  height: number;
};

type OembedProps = SharedMediaProps & {
  /** Enable video autoplay */
  autoplay?: boolean;
  /** Enable video loop */
  loop?: boolean;
  /** Allow fullscreen */
  allowFullscreen?: boolean;
  /** Allow picture-in-picture */
  allowPictureInPicture?: boolean;
  /** oEmbed title */
  title?: string;
};
```

Then in my React component, I have:

```
export function Media({
  type,
  title,
  width,
  height,
  src,
  autoplay = false,
  loop = false,
  allowFullscreen = true,
  allowPictureInPicture = true,
}: MediaProps) {
```

but I'm getting notices saying `title`, `width`, `height`, `autoplay`, `loop`, `allowFullscreen`, `allowPictureInPicture` aren't defined.

For example, the specific notice I'm getting is:

> Property 'allowFullscreen' does not exist on type
> 'MediaProps'.ts(2339)

It's also happening on other components I've created.

Comment: I don't see `allowFullscreen` anywhere in your type definitions

Comment: Or `OembedProps` at all. Please give a [mre].

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that. I've updated it, didn't get the full copy and paste. @TobiasS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, move the `type` property into the not shared props, so it can be used to discrimitate the type:

```
type SharedMediaProps = {
   /** Media source URL */
   src: string;
};

type ImageMediaProps = SharedMediaProps & {
   /** Media type */
   type: "image";
   /** Image alternate text */
   alt: string;
   /** Image width */
   width: number;
   /** Image height */
   height: number;
};

type OembedProps = SharedMediaProps & {
   /** Media type */
   type: "oembed";
   /** Enable video autoplay */
   autoplay?: boolean;
   /** Enable video loop */
   loop?: boolean;
   /** Allow fullscreen */
   allowFullscreen?: boolean;
   /** Allow picture-in-picture */
   allowPictureInPicture?: boolean;
   /** oEmbed title */
   title?: string;
};
```

Then define `MediaProps` as union of those types:

```
type MediaProps = ImageMediaProps | OembedProps;
```

After all this you still can't deconstruct the property in the paramenter because you have to discriminate the type first:

```
export function Media(props: MediaProps) {
   if(props.type === "image") {
      const {alt, width, height} = props;
   } else {
      const {autoplay, loop, allowFullscreen, allowPictureInPicture, title} = props;
   }
}
```

Demo: https://tsplay.dev/NBkVnm

Comment: Beautiful, even better, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll need to use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) on your MediaProps assignment.

`export type MediaProps = ImageMediaProps & OembedProps;`

Comment: Bingo! That did it, thanks!

Comment: But this way `MediaProps` has ALWAYS both the attributes of ImageMediaProps and OembedProps types. Don't you want to have ONLY the ImageMediaProps  when type is `image` and ONLY the OembedProps when the type is `oembed`? if so check my answer

Comment: I think what you're proposing is a better solution @coglialoro but itself is outside the scope of the original ask and requires refactoring `export function Media` arguments